# What HTTP request headers are important/commonly used?

Tags: http, tcp, webserver

I'm writing a web server, and I'd like to know what HTTP request headers (sent by the client) are the most common and thus that I should focus on implementing.

Right now, I only support `Accept` and `Host`.

Comment: What type of clients are you writing your web server for?  It's hard to say what request headers are most common without having some sort of usage profile.

Comment: Generic web browsers—Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, etc.

Comment: There is a whole list of them here. I don't know what you need them for; but if your application needs to handle everything and it is facing the public; you might consider implementing all of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields The core set is part of RFC2616: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: Ya, I have to agree with @vcsjones: asking what headers you should implement in a web server is like asking which keys on a keyboard should work. In the end they all should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure on your scope but since you are interested in serving web browsers, you should have a look into the RFC ([HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html))
Read about what the server `MUST` process

Answer (score 0):

The [Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Cookie) header might be a good idea, as would the Content-Length header; without Content-Length you won't be able to handle POST and PUT requests properly.